# Holoeverywhere lint errors

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I am developing an android application in which I use HoloEverywhere. The implementation all went well, but now I want to create a signed application.

Before being able to create a signed application, all the code must pass the lint error check. However, Holoeverywhere gives me 16 errors.

Am I supposed to disable those errors to be fatal? Or is there a fix for those problems?

Some of the errors I get:

```
This class should be public (org.holoeverywhere.slider.SliderMenuGroupIndicatorView)
This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)
Class referenced in the layout file, Internal.DialogTitle, was not found in the project or the libraries
Class referenced in the layout file, Internal.ExpandedMenuView, was not found in the project or the libraries
Class referenced in the layout file, Internal.NumberPickerEditText, was not found in the project or the libraries
Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent"
```

I am using the latest version of HoloEverywhere from their GitHub: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an issue that can be opened in the repository. Anyway I usually disable this errors inside the `lint.xml` in my projects.